# Tangent vector and sequence of points

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be the graph of a $C^1$ function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is open. Suppose there is a sequence $s_k$ converging to $p \in M$ such that $$\lim_{k}\frac{s_k-p}{|s_k-p|}=v$$ for some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

> Show that $v$ is tangent to $M$ at $p$, i.e. $v=(w ,df_xw)=(w, \nabla f (x) \cdot w)$, where $w=(v_1,...,v_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(x,f(x))=p$

Here is my try. We have $s_k=(x_k,f(x_k))$ for some $x_k \in X$ and therefore $v=\displaystyle \lim_{k}\frac{s_k-p}{|s_k-p|}=\lim_k\frac{1}{|s_k-p|}\left(x_k-x,f(x_k)-f(x) \right )=\lim_k\frac{|x_k-x|}{|s_k-p|}\left(\frac{x_k-x}{|x_k-x|},\frac{f(x_k)-f(x)}{|x_k-x|} \right )$.

But $\displaystyle \frac{|x_k-x|}{|s_k-p|}=\frac{|x_k-x|}{\sqrt{|x_k-x|^2+|f(x_k)-f(x)|^2}}\in \left [\frac{|x_k-x|}{\sqrt{|x_k-x|^2(1+|\nabla f(x)|^2o(|x_k-x|)^2)}},1\right]$ because $f$ is differentiable, so $v=\displaystyle \lim_k\left(\frac{x_k-x}{|x_k-x|},\frac{f(x_k)-f(x)}{|x_k-x|} \right )$.

Calling $w:=\displaystyle \lim_k\left(\frac{x_k-x}{|x_k-x|}\right )$ I would be done, if I knew that this limit existed. Do you have any suggestion for this? Is the above correct?

Comment: Did you write down (and use) what it means for $f$ to to be differentiable at $x$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited my post to make it clearer where I used this fact. Your hint was 'use differentiability of $f$ again'?

Comment: Perhaps more straightforward is to prove that $\|v\|=1$ and $v^2/v^1=f'(x)$.

Comment: @Kajelad Can you please explain your notation?

Comment: That $\|v\|$ is the magnitude of $v$ and $v^2/v^1$ is the ratio of the second and first components of $v$.

Comment: @Kajelad, not good. The first component is a vector. Leonardo, yes. Use derivative to rewrite  $f(x_k)-f(x)$.